# How to send a value to a web browser input field

Tags: javascript

I would like to send value to a web browser input field, I think the data type is float (e.g. 1.00).

Inspector tool shows the following elements for the input field:

```
<div _ngcontent-rvn-c64="" 
    class="input"><input _ngcontent-rvn-c64="" 
    class="font-weight-bold" type="text">
</div>
```

I tried the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].focus();
document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value = 2;

document.getElementsByClassName('font-weight-bold')[0].focus();
document.getElementsByClassName('font-weight-bold')[0].value = 2; 
( also tried with these values 2.00 and "2" and parseFloat(2) )
```

It just prints the value 2 to Console and does not input this value into the input field.

Comment: I think it's likely you're loading the JS before the HTML which causes the element to not exist yet, add the JS script after the html and see if that helps (at the end of `<body>` perhaps). However, it would be more useful if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we don't have to guess

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the values before the DOM is ready
try giving settimeout

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('font-weight-bold')[0].focus();
            document.getElementsByClassName('font-weight-bold')[0].setAttribute('value','2');
        }, 10);
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-rvn-c64="" class="input" id="inp" >
   <input _ngcontent-rvn-c64="" class="font-weight-bold" type="text" val="test " />
  </div>
```